# adding timestamp to real time data log matlab

Tags: matlab, timestamp, real-time

I'm trying to find a way to timestamp a string value received from a USB port in real time - every 0.5 s - and save it into a file.

So far I'm using the 'record' function to save the string value, but I haven't been able to add the timestamp to it. Reading through the questions, found someone had used the 'now' funciton, but they do not describe the way to do it. The string value I'm using as example to produce the code is the following:

> 1      Recording on 12-Feb-2015 at 15:57:13.940. Binary data in little endian format.
>
> 2      < 34 ascii values.
>          Timestamp,4.5,5.5,6.5,7.5,8.5,...
>
> 3      < 34 ascii values.
>          Timestamp,4.5,5.5,6.5,7.5,8.5,...
>
> 4      < 34 ascii values.
>          Timestamp,4.5,5.5,6.5,7.5,8.5,..."

and the code that so far I have developed is the following:

```
%// start code
delete(instrfind);
s = serial('COM5');
set(s,'BaudRate',57600);
set(s,'terminator','CR');

%// Open Serial COM Port
fopen(s);

%// start save file
s.RecordDetail = 'verbose';
s.RecordName = datestr(now,30)
record(s,'on')

%// start time
tic; 
hold on;
count = 1; 
t = 0;

keepLooping = true;
while keepLooping

    time(count)=toc;
    count = count +1;
    out   = fscanf(s);
    fprintf(s,'%s','RS232?')
    out1 = strsplit(out,',');
    s.UserData = count;
    p(count) = str2double(out1(2));
    k(count) = str2double(out1(3));
    g(count) = str2double(out1(4));
    h(count) = str2double(out1(5));

%// plotting of the variables continues from this point.
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess that the problem is that you get some system time making no sense. For a comprehensive time stamp you can do following:

```
datestr(datetime,'yyyy-mmm-dd HH:MM:SS:FFF')
```

You get the time as a *char* vector using the `datetime` function for the time and the `datestr` function for the format and casting. Since you seem to have done some programming before I think that you will be able to google this later to find the format you want to use. That may differ country by country I guess.

Please comment if this is not what you want. Good Luck!

Comment: Hi Patrik, thank you for your reply, however it is not really what I'm trying to do. The suggestion you gave me is to modify the time stamp in the file name produced when saving it. What I'm after is trying to add a time stamp to each line produced in the file when obtaining data from the USB port. The time stamp in the file name is an alternative to keep track of the time of each reading. Hope I was a bit more clear this time. Thank you for your advise.

Comment: @MiguelAlvarado No that is not what I suggested. I showed you how to get the time as a string in matlab. What you have to do then is add this to your printout. `fprintf(s, '[%s] %s', datestr(datetime,'yyyy-mmm-dd HH:MM:SS:FFF'), 'RS232?')`. Thought it to be straight forward. If you want to get the time from the usb connection or if you want the time difference only, you must write this in the question

Comment: Hi @Patrik, I quite new with programming so thank you for detailing your explanation. I used the command line and it did the job, just changed datetime to now for my purposes. Thanks again.